# What can be used to pull xml data besides http request?

Tags: xml, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have two servers. I'm trying to pull an xml file from one server to the next. I was told that the server that is hosting the file doesn't allow remote http requests. What is another way I can get the xml data?

There must be someway that itunes or other programs would pull xml data?

Here is an example of the dynamically created xml page:
http://panel.secc.org/index.php/sermon/getXmlSeriesList

Comment: If it's a static file, one thinks immediately of FTP or its more secure variants.  However you seem to be asking about making dynamic requests.  The fact that the server "hosting the file allow remote http requests" is not necessarily a deal breaker.  Perhaps there is a Web server elsewhere on the network that has read-access on the one that "is hosting the file"?  If the target server has this access, it could simply map the network drive on the other server and do an OS-based file copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have accounts on both servers and ssh access on both then you can use scp.  This is fine for interactive transfers from the shell.

If you are writing your own application to pull the data, then you can probably find a library to do what scp does from the shell; it depends on your programming language.

If both machines in the transfer are servers, I don't see how client applications like iTunes fit in.